# Combine a .htaccess for Joomla and Magento

Tags: .htaccess, magento, joomla

In the root of my website I built a site with Joomla. In the subfolder \webshop\ I build a site with Magento.

I can’t get my .htaccess file right for this. For now the Joomla site works well, and the Magento site also. But I can’t click on for example \Contact us\ in Magento. The link (http://example.com/webshop/contacts) leads me back to the homepage. But when I edit the link to (http://example.com/webshop/index.php/contacts) it works perfectly. So there is something wrong.

For clarity, when people go to http://example.nl, they should go to my Joomla site, but when people go to http://example.nl/webshop, they should go to my webshop. (/webshop is also the location of the Magento folder in my root, of course)

I also want to use http://example.com and not http://www.example.com. (Also very important for SSL in Magento, because I have only a SSL certificate for http:// and not for http://www.)

I found out that when I use `Rewrite base /webshop` in the .htaccess, it works perfect, but then the Joomla site doesn't work. I combined the Magento .htaccess with my own. I had to upload it with pastebin, because this site doesn't allow links and WWW. What I've done wrong there?

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mv5whinq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Magento installed into the subdirectory named `webshop`

In the Magento configuration, you must change the **Base URL** to include your subdirectory.

1. Go to **System > Configuration > Web**
2. Change **Base URL** to **http://yoursite.com/webshop/** (also update your **Secure Base URL**)
3. Open your Magento .htaccess file in your `webshop` directory and change the following:

   Find:
   `#RewriteBase /magento/`

   Change to:
   `RewriteBase /webshop/`
4. Save your Magento .htaccess file & flush your Magento cache folders `var/cache`

Comment: Thank you for your response! That worked! I thought you can't use 2 .htasccess files. (My previous hosting provider told me that)
Many thanks! Should I install a Joomla .htaccess file in the root, and use this Magento .htaccess file in the /webshop folder?

Comment: The .htaccess file in subdirectories can override the .htaccess file in it's parent directories.  You can't have two different .htacess files in the same directory (which is probably what your previous hosting provider meant).  Also you are correct.  You want the Joomla .htaccess file for Joomla in your root (since Joomla is installed in the root), and the Magento .htaccess file in your `webshop` directory, where Magento is located.

Comment: Thanks! No that was not what me meant for sure. Because I had also there a .htaccess in the root, and a .htaccess in the /webshop folder.
Thank you for your help. Can't give you a vote because I am new here!